# APNS: The certificate is revoked

Tags: ios, asp.net, certificate, apple-push-notifications, mmc

My iPad app uses an ASP.Net server to send APNS messages (using MoonAPNS) to the app when a new document is uploaded to the server.

I used MMC to import new certificates last week (Thursday) and had it working with an ad-hoc distribution version of the app.

Today, I tried to upload a new document to the server and received the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The certificate is revoked
```

The things is, between last Thursday and today I haven't revoked any certificates / provisioning profiles / etc.

Anyone have an idea of why this might have happened?

Comment: Do you get this error with the pem file when sending notifications? Or in XCode when creating an ipa?

Comment: No errors when creating the .ipa. Haven't been able to send any notifications today.

Comment: Then it looks like the certificates associated with your pem files (the ones you create for APNS under the App Ids section in developer portal) have been revoked

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try to look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up trying to figure this one out and brute-force fixed it by removing then renewing all of the server certificates.

Still no idea what caused the initial problem but this at least is a work-around.